# How to make dependent parametrization in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

For example, I have this test data:

```
PARAMS = {'pic1': [1, 2, 3], 'pic2': [14, 15], 'pic3': [100, 200, 300]}
```

I need to download each key-picture from this `PARAMS` and generate separate tests `[1, 2, 3]`, that will use this picture. After that when each test of `'pic1': [1, 2, 3]` pair ends, remove picture, then download the next one, and so on...
Roughly speaking, generated tests should look like this:

```
test_pic[pic1-1]
test_pic[pic1-2]
test_pic[pic1-3]
test_pic[pic2-14]
test_pic[pic2-15]
test_pic[pic3-100]
test_pic[pic3-200]
test_pic[pic3-300]
```

but inside will be a download image logic.

I did not find a way how to do it in pytest.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a task for the indirect parametrizaton to me.

#### Prepare parameters

First things first: `pytest.mark.parametrize` expects parameters to be passed as a list of tuples, with data ordered by arg names, for example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('spam,eggs', [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])
```

will generate three tests:

- `spam=1, eggs=2`,
- `spam=3, eggs=4`,
- `spam=5, eggs=6`.

So you have to transform the `PARAMS` dict into list of tuples with one number per dict key. There are lots of ways to do that, one solution being:

```
PARAMS = {'pic1': [1, 2, 3],
          'pic2': [14, 15],
          'pic3': [100, 200, 300]}

test_pic_params = [(key, el) for key, nums in PARAMS.items()
                   for el in nums]


@pytest.mark.parametrize('file,num', test_pic_params)
def test_pic(file, num):
    assert True
```

Check whether the tests are generated correctly:

```
$ pytest --collect-only --quiet test_spam.py
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic1-1]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic1-2]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic1-3]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic2-14]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic2-15]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic3-100]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic3-200]
test_spam.py::test_pic[pic3-300]

no tests ran in 0.07 seconds
```

#### Indirect parametrization

Now you want to process the `file` parameter before the test, so the test gets the downloaded file for `pic1` instead of `pic1`. This can be done with indirect parametrization. What you need to do is:

- implement a fixture named `file` (it is important that the fixture has the same name as the test parameter, or `pytest` won't recognize and apply it);
- add `indirect=['file']` to parametrization marker.

This way, `pic1` is first passed to `file()` fixture and the result of the fixture is then passed to the test. Extended example:

```
import pathlib
import pytest


PARAMS = {'pic1': [1, 2, 3], 
          'pic2': [14, 15],
          'pic3': [100, 200, 300]}

test_pic_params = [(key, el) for key, nums in PARAMS.items()
                   for el in nums]


@pytest.fixture
def file(request):
    pic = request.param
    # this will just create an empty file named 'pic1' etc;
    # replace it with file download logic
    filename = pathlib.Path(pic)
    filename.touch()
    # pass filename instead of pic to test
    yield filename
    # after test finishes, we remove downloaded file
    filename.unlink()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('file,num', test_pic_params, indirect=['file'])
def test_pic(file, num):
    assert file.is_file()
```

### Edit:

> What I need is remove file `'pic1'` after tests `test_pic[pic1-1] , test_pic[pic1-2], test_pic[pic1-3]`. Then download new file `pic2`.

Although this is surely possible, keep in mind that this will violate the atomicity of single test runs, so for example, you will loose the ability of running tests in parallel.

If you want to track the current state of the test run, just do it in the fixture. When the number is the first one in the corresponding list, download the file; remove the file on last number:

```
@pytest.fixture
def file(request):
    pic = request.param
    num = request.node.callspec.params['num']
    filename = pathlib.Path(pic)
    if num == PARAMS[pic][0]:  # download here
        filename.touch()
    yield filename
    if num == PARAMS[pic][-1]:  # remove here
        filename.unlink()
```

A better approach IMO would be using [disk cache](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html), caching the file when downloaded for the first time; this would make the test runs atomic again.

Comment: First of all, thank you. But your example will destroy file after every test.
What I need is remove file 'pic1' after tests `test_pic[pic1-1] , test_pic[pic1-2], test_pic[pic1-3]`. Then download new file pic2.

Comment: To be honest, I don't like the idea of doing that, thus not approaching it in the answer. However, tracking the current test by args is an easy task - see the "edit" section in the updated answer for an example.

Comment: I see your point about parallelization, you are right. Now I don't need to run the tests in parallel, but I will keep in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!